# Custom checkbox introduces padding issues

Tags: android, checkbox

In order to create a custom `checkbox`, I made an xml file containing the following lines:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/online"/>
     <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/offline" />
</selector>
```

The purpose was to  change the checked and unchecked drawables, and it worked just fine. The only issue that occurred is that the text of the checkboxes goes under the check/unchecked drawable.

Comment: You can try `android:leftPadding` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use have to use padding :-

```
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/remember_me"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:button="@drawable/check_box_selector"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="remember_me" />
```

Comment: are you referring to the padding left propriety?

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin hahahahahaha